# how do not duplicate a action in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

js:

```
 $(".test").focusout(function(){
    var qtdCont = parseInt($(this).val());
      if(qtdCont > 0)
      {
         var qtdProd     = $(".value").val();
         var qtdProdInt  = parseInt(qtdProd);
         var qtdProdTot  = qtdProd-qtdCont;
         $(".value").val(qtdProdTot);
      }
 });
```

**Demo:** [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dNEmD/18/)

i need the subtract only the fist time when he lose the focus.

because if u go's back and focusout again, the subtraction (obviously) will  happen again.

how can i control that ?

thank you.

Comment: Two things: First, I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do. Second, *edit boxes should not be used as command inducing controls*. Give the user a button to click on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `data` in the dom element:

```
$(".test").focusout(function(){
     var qtdCont = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(qtdCont > 0 && $(this).data('done') == undefined)
    {
         var qtdProd     = $(".value").val();
         var qtdProdInt  = parseInt(qtdProd);
         var qtdProdTot  = qtdProd-qtdCont;
         $(".value").val(qtdProdTot);
        $(this).data('done', true);
     }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dNEmD/19/

**UPDATE**

```
$(".test").focusout(function(){
     var qtdCont = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(qtdCont > 0 && 
         ($(this).data('done') == undefined || $(this).data('done') == false))
    {
         var qtdProd     = $(".value").val();
         var qtdProdInt  = parseInt(qtdProd);
         var qtdProdTot  = qtdProd-qtdCont;
         $(".value").val(qtdProdTot);
        $(this).data('done', true);
     }
});

$(".test").change(function(){ //if value was changed
     $(this).data('done', false);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dNEmD/27/

Comment: @Neal: works perfect, but if i go back and change the value again, the subtract will not work.

Comment: @ric_bfa: see this fiddle for updating only that row: http://jsfiddle.net/dNEmD/28/

Answer (score 0):

keep a semaphore variable at the top somewhere.  It's start out false, then the first time you focus out set it true.  It remains true for the rest of the programs lifespan and you do not allow certain parts of focusout code to execute when the semaphore variable is true.